# How to use the = sign in captions

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like my axis to be labeled `$s(t)=\delta(t)$`, but this does not work because of the `=` sign (key-value separator). I had a look into the "Comprehensive Symbols Guide" referenced here: http://w2.syronex.com/jmr/tex/texsym.old.html
I also found `\equal`, but it seems like another package is used and to avoid that .... does anyone know how to handle that?

For comepleteness, this is what I need to compile.

```
% \begin{axis}[ylabel=$u_1(t)=\delta(t)$,ymax=1.2] does not work
\begin{axis}[ylabel=$u_1(t)\ne\delta(t)$,ymax=1.2] % different symbol, of course
    \addplot [->,>=latex] coordinates {
        (0, 0)
        (0, 1)
    };
\end{axis}
```

Comment: What about to protect the equal sign with braces `{=}`?

Comment: @Sigur: Yes, that's the right thing to do. Same thing is true if the titles contain commas. Equal signs and commas are parsed by the key-value system, so they need to be grouped using braces to protect them. Would you mind writing an answer?

Comment: @wal-o-mat: You should always post complete minimal example documents instead of code snippets. That saves others the work of having to fill in the missing bits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Jake, thanks for the confirmation. So, the solution to that problem is to use braces to protect the equal sign, also to protect commas.

`ylabel={$u_1(t)=\delta(t)$}`

Regards.

Comment: Put the braces around the whole math expression. If you put them only around the "=" it will affect the spacing before and after the "=".

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially answers like this which do not only help to solve this specific problem, but help to understand how to think of the problem.